# save/restore weights of a tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, parameters, save, load

I'm trying to save and restore parameters of a tensorflow model. The code does save the parameters to the given path, but when I try to restore the last checkpoint, perform an operation, and then save again, it doesn't return the last checkpoint. what should I do?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os



v1 = tf.Variable(1.32, name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(1.33, name="v2")


saver = tf.train.Saver()

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()


with tf.Session() as sess:


    sess.run(init)


    print (v2.eval(sess)) 

    saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model")
    print("Model restored.")


for i in range(10):

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname('/tmp/'))

    print(ckpt)

    sess = tf.Session()

    if(ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):


        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

        x = sess.run("v2:0")
        x = x + 1

        print(x)


        saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model", global_step = i)

        sess.close()
```

Comment: have you tried to reset the graph (tf.reset_default_graph() ) after saving it for the first time.

Comment: I tried it, but when I try to restore the parameters, it shows this error, File "test.py", line 44, in <module>
    v1 = v1 + 1
TypeError: can't concat int to bytes